# string to a dom document in java 

Tags: java, dom, netbeans

I have a string which has an xml inside. I want to write this to a `Document` in java so i can later retrieve the attributes within it and store them in other strings. Could someone provide me with an example of this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more details are necessary for a proper answer but you can start with the [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) like this:

```
  DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()
  Document doc = db.parse(yourstring);
```

You now have a Document from which you can access your XML attributes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html.  Hopefully it will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

This is a good example of how to parse out some XML.  This should be a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(myXMLString.getBytes());